# How does Professor Charles Xavier's telepathy/telekinesis work?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I know that Prof X has psionic abilities,

- Inducing illusions
- Mind Control and Mental Suggestion
- Temporary mental or physical paralysis
- Loss of specific memories, or total amnesia
- Sensing the presence of mutants within a small radius

But I want to know how he does these, does he use brain waves or something like that.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean when you ask "how he does it"?

Comment: I meant if he uses electromagnetic waves, like others call it "brain waves" or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously Charles is using Telepathy to do all these things and I am not sure there is anything canonical on how he actually does it, ie via brain waves.

My take,

In [SUPERPOWER wiki](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Telepathy) it states,

> Telepathic Communication, which is the ability to transmit information
>   from mind to another, and Telepathic Perception, which is the ability
>   to receive information from another mind.

And has this useful piece of information

> Does not work on mindless beings (corpses, animated objects, robots,
>   etc.).

When sending or receiving information through the air the use of radio waves (electromagnetic radiation) is at present the most popular method of doing so.  So, because telepathy does not work on dead and in animated objects, this shows that brain function is needed and sending and receiving information directly to the brain requires some sort of electromagnetic radiation in wave form to be emitted from the brain. What you want to call that could possible be considered "brain waves" I guess.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, that if these brain waves are electromagnetic waves or not. Thanks, mate. Btw love your username.